# SendInput sends "num8" when I want to send "vk_up" ? How come?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

Well I'm trying to make a simple modification for a game, and this is the code that emulate the key press:

```
#define PWNFUNC(a) static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL a(AMX *amx, cell *params)
PWNFUNC(EmulateKeyPressINPUT)
{
    // This structure will be used to create the keyboard
    // input event.
    INPUT ip;

    // Set up a generic keyboard event.
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    ip.ki.wVk = params[2]; // virtual-key code for the "a" key
    switch(params[1])
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
        break;
        case WM_KEYUP:
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        break;
    }
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    return 1;
}
```

the problem with this is that somehow when I want to send an arrow up key the numpad8 key is sent (maybe it's because of my hardware keyboard?).
When I press the arrow key on my keyboar the aircraft in the game goes forward.. and when I emulate the up arrow, then my thrusters change rotation (rotation change is mapped to num 8).
the same happens with respectively arrow down - num2, left arrow - num4 and right arrow - num6.

What is going on?

__

maybe unrelated but if you want to see the code which controls the aircraft, this is it:

(it's in PAWN - a scripting language)

```
        #define KEYPRESS_DOWN 0x0100
        #define KEYPRESS_UP 0x0101
        GetMovementSpeed(pos[0][0],pos[0][1],pos[0][2],true);
        new Float:speed = floatsqroot(pos[0][0]*pos[0][0]+pos[0][1]*pos[0][1]+pos[0][2]*pos[0][2])*174.0;
        if ( speed > 260.0 )
            speed = 260.0;

        if(GetVehicleModel() == 520)//f-22 airplane
        {
            static sent = 0;
            if(IsKeyDown(VK_TAB))
            {
                if(speed < 200.0)
                {
                    EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,VK_DOWN);
                    EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_DOWN,VK_UP);
                    sent = 1;
                    DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "GO birdy!! gooo!!!!" );

                }
                else if(speed > 210.0)
                {
                    EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,VK_UP);
                    EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_DOWN,VK_DOWN);
                    sent = 2;
                    DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "TOO fastststs!!!! SOTTP STOP!!!" );
                }
            }
            else if(sent == 1)
            {
                EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,VK_UP);
                sent = 0;
                DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "You won't see this message" );
            }
            else if(sent == 2)
            {
                EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,VK_DOWN);
                sent = 0;
                DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "Nor this one, c'mon if you do, you can notice a change in one f**king frame between 2 other frames?!" );
            }
            else
            {
                DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "Something other is going on.. our relation ship is too complicated :(" );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "Well, f**k you too, no autopilot if you're not in an F-22.." );
        }
```

Comment: Try using the scancode and see if anything changes. Just in case it didn't pop out at you, num8 is the up arrow on the numpad, and likewise for the others. However, `VK_UP` has always been the up directional arrow for me.

Comment: what would the hardware scancode be, also VK_UP?

Comment: You can try [one](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/scancodes1.html) [of](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/scancodes2.html) [these](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/scancodes3.html).

Comment: oh that pointed it out -> "At power-on or software reset (see the "Reset" command) the keyboard performs a diagnostic self-test referred to as BAT (Basic Assurance Test) and loads the following default values:  

Typematic delay 500 ms. 
Typematic rate 10.9 cps. 
Scan code set 2. 
Set all keys typematic/make/break. ", now How do I send that make code? one time E0 and one time 48?

Comment: so 75 is num8 and E0,75 is uparrow ;F

Comment: well, time to spend much time on making a C array for this

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to send those ones. I haven't had to resort to scancodes.

Comment: Orr.... I enable the extended key flag, will check if this works

Comment: Good news then. You might want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [scancodes 2 page](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/scancodes2.html) and the main page of it, the hardware default scancode set is 2 and the code for arrow up is E0,75 and for numpad8 just plain 75, that means that the arrow key is an extended key, so you need to enable the extended key flag. This code succesfully enables you to manipulate the data from the script:

```
PWNFUNC(EmulateKeyPressINPUT)
{
    // This structure will be used to create the keyboard
    // input event.
    INPUT ip;

    // Set up a generic keyboard event.
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    if(params[4] == 1)
    {
        ip.ki.wScan = params[2]; // hardware scan code for key
        ip.ki.wVk = 0; // virtual-key code for the  key
        ip.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
    }
    else
    {
        ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
        ip.ki.wVk = params[2]; // virtual-key code for the  key
    }

    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    if(params[3] == 1)
    {
        ip.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
    }
    if(params[1] == 1)
    {
        ip.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    }
    return SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

example usage for the script:

```
        GetMovementSpeed(pos[0][0],pos[0][1],pos[0][2],true);
        new Float:speed = floatsqroot(pos[0][0]*pos[0][0]+pos[0][1]*pos[0][1]+pos[0][2]*pos[0][2])*174.0;
        if ( speed > 260.0 )
            speed = 260.0;

        if(GetVehicleModel() == 520)//f-22 airplane
        {
            static sent = 0;
            static status = 0;
            static vKEY_UP = VK_UP;
            static vKEY_DOWN = VK_DOWN;
            static bool:extended = false;
            static bool:hardware = false;
            if(IsKeyDown(VK_KEY_0))
            {
                vKEY_UP = VK_NUMPAD8;
                vKEY_DOWN = VK_NUMPAD2;
            }
            else if(IsKeyDown(VK_KEY_9))
            {
                vKEY_UP = VK_UP;
                vKEY_DOWN = VK_DOWN;
            }
            else if(IsKeyDown(VK_KEY_8))
            {
                extended = true;
            }
            else if(IsKeyDown(VK_KEY_7))
            {
                extended = false;
            }
            else if(IsKeyDown(VK_KEY_6))
            {
                hardware = true;
            }
            else if(IsKeyDown(VK_KEY_5))
            {
                hardware = false;
            }
            DrawText( id,50.0,170.0,0xFFFFFFFF, sprintf("UP: %x DOWN: %x Extended: %d Hardware: %d",vKEY_UP,vKEY_DOWN,extended,hardware) );
            if(IsKeyDown(VK_TAB))
            {
                if(speed < 200.0)
                {
                    if(status == 0)
                    {
                        new PressedKeys[2];
                        PressedKeys[0] = EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,vKEY_DOWN,extended,hardware);
                        PressedKeys[1] = EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_DOWN,vKEY_UP,extended,hardware);
                        DrawTextTimed(id,50.0,210.0,0xFFFFFFFF,sprintf("Presses:{%d,%d} if(speed < 200.0)",PressedKeys[0],PressedKeys[1]),2000,250,0);
                        sent = 1;
                        status = 1;
                    }
                    DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "GO birdy!! gooo!!!!" );
                }
                else if(speed > 210.0)
                {
                    if(status == 0)
                    {
                        new PressedKeys[2];
                        PressedKeys[0] = EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,vKEY_UP,extended,hardware);
                        PressedKeys[1] = EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_DOWN,vKEY_DOWN,extended,hardware);
                        DrawTextTimed(id,50.0,210.0,0xFFFFFFFF,sprintf("Presses:{%d,%d} if(speed > 210.0)",PressedKeys[0],PressedKeys[1]),2000,250,1);
                        sent = 2;
                        status = 1;
                    }
                    DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "TOO fastststs!!!! SOTTP STOP!!!" );
                }
                else
                {
                    status = 0;
                    EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,vKEY_UP,extended,hardware);
                    EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,vKEY_DOWN,extended,hardware);
                }
            }
            else if(sent == 1)
            {
                DrawTextTimed(id,50.0,220.0,0xFFFFFFFF,sprintf("Presses:{%d} if(sent == 1)",EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,vKEY_UP,extended,hardware)),2000,250,2);
                sent = 0;
                status = 0;
                DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "You won't see this message" );
            }
            else if(sent == 2)
            {
                DrawTextTimed(id,50.0,230.0,0xFFFFFFFF,sprintf("Presses:{%d} if(sent == 1)",EmulateKeyPress(KEYPRESS_UP,vKEY_DOWN,extended,hardware)),2000,250,3);
                sent = 0;
                status = 0;
                DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "Nor this one, c'mon if you do, you can notice a change in one frame between 2 other frames?!" );
            }
            else
            {
                DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "Something other is going on.. our relation ship is too complicated :(" );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DrawText( id,50.0,160.0,0xFFFFFFFF, "Well, no autopilot if you're not in an F-22.." );
        }
```

allows you to change the flags with 5,6,7,8 keys and the input keys with 9 and 0

Answer (score 2):

Just add an extra flag `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY`:

```
input.ki.dwflags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
```

Answer (score -1):

The result of some software designers misunderstanding, notepad is function,  mame 0.102 is 0 - 9

```
33 numpad 9 pgup
34 numpad 3 pgdn
35 numpad 1 end
36 numpad 7 home
37 numpad 4 left arrow
38 numpad 8 up arrow
39 numpad 6 right arrow
40 numpad 2 down arrow
45 numpad 0 insert
46 numpad . delete
```

notepad is 0 - 9, mame 0.102 is function

```
96-105   numpad 0 - 9 
96 ins
97 end
98 down arrow
99 pgdn
100 left arrow
101 
102 right arrow
103 home
104 up arrow
105 pgup
106 numpad *
107 numpad +
109 numpad -
110 numpad .
111 numpad /
```